# For what reason doesn’t SQL allow a variable to be assigned a value using syntax @i =100;?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Unlike programming languages, SQL doesn’t allow variable to be assigned a value using the following syntax ( instead we must use `SET` or `SELECT` ):

```
@i=100; //error
```

Is there particular reason why SQL doesn’t allow this?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first reason that comes to mind is that SQL uses the '='-sign for both comparing of values as setting of values. This means that it requires a different syntax to distinguish between comparing and setting of the values. In (some) other programming there is a distinction between setting and comparing the values with the use of the '='-sign and the '=='-sign.
For example in SQL:

```
SET @a = 100 --To set the value of @a.
if (@a = 100) -- To compare the value of @a.
```

For example in C#:

```
a = 100; //To set the value of a.
if (a == 100) //To compare the value of a.
```

Answer (score 9):

Why does any language use the syntax it uses?

To maintain conventions, prevent ambiguity, and simplify parsing.

Notice that the syntax of `SET` statements (properly called *assignment statements*) is similar to the syntax in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable SET somecolumn = 100;
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe they did this deliberately just to annoy you.

Comment: Wait? Do you mean it wasn't to deliberately annoy me, but rather someone else?!?!?

Answer (score 4):

You may as well say why can't I do this in c#?

```
SELECT * FROM MyArray[]
```

Why must I iterate and mess around with Console.WriteLine? It's just a set collection of data that I want to see in one go.

Comment: `from item in MyArray select item`

Comment: @John Saunders: you didn't *have* to do that... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Those variables are part of Transact-SQL, not the SQL standard.

SQL was not designed to write procedural code, so its support for anything other than set operations is largely bolted on in proprietary extensions.

Comment: +1 for a likely answer. SET is ANSI SQL though

Answer (score 3):

why do your need a "@" at the beginning of a variable name? to help parse the commands

The `SET` or `SELECT` helps differentiate assignment from comparisons, it is just the way TSQL was designed.

use:

```
SET @i=100 --for single assignments
```

and

```
SELECT @i=100,@a=200,@c=300  --for multiple assignements, which is
                             --faster than the equivalent multiple SET commands
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, SQL isn't a programming language.

I can't say that I know the reason.  However, it likely has something to do with the intended use of SQL.  Namely, working with data.  Who works with a lot of data?  Business people.  The language, as such, uses more words and fewer symbols.  Compare the style of  VisualBasic to C++.

Comment: "SQL isn't a progamming language `[citation needed]` "  What exactly makes one language a programming language and another language not a programming language?

Comment: SQL is respected as a 4G programming language; Java/C#/etc are considered 3G.  SQL has a higher rating due to closer to natural English syntax, among a few other things I forgot from school...

Comment: @Bill Karwin That depends on what your definition of the 'is' is... ;)  SQL is two parts, a Data Manipulation Language and a Data Definition Language.  It depends on how you want to split the hair.  :)

Comment: @OMG Ponies One problem with the whole 3G/4G thing is that the G stand for Generation.  So, bolting on top another meaning to 4G I.e. not the 4th iteration of language types, but rather calling it a 'rating' is problematic.

Comment: @George Marian: Doesn't change the fact 3G/4G classifies programming languages ;)

Comment: @OMG Ponies Well, we're not the first people to have this debate. I doubt we'll be the last. :)  Also, was SQL considered a 4G language when it was created?

Comment: 4GL is a term for a language that is specialized to a domain of work, and provides greater abstraction for programmers.  A 4GL is "further from the machine" and closer to the domain.  *Domain-specific language*, or DSL, is a more recent term for a similar idea.  The term 4GL didn't catch on until 1982, but SQL and even some earlier languages do meet its definition.

Answer (score 2):

> After a variable is declared, it is initialized to NULL. Use the SET statement to assign a value that is not NULL to a declared variable.

So says [TSQL SET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx).  I don't remember having to use the [SET keyword in Oracle's PLSQL](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html).

Comment: Givem PL/SQL syntax is Ada-like, that's not surprising...

Comment: Add that MySQL also only uses the SET keyword for system level variables, and I imagine PostgreSQL is similar to Oracle...